# Can fish shell handle if statements within if statements?

Tags: fish

I'm trying to get my config.fish to work, but it's not working as expected, and I really can't understand why. The best I can do is guess that maybe Fish can't handle if statements within if statements? Here's my code:

```
echo "so far so good"
if status --is-interactive
    # Chips: fish plugin manager
    if [ -e ~/.config/chips/build.fish ] ; . ~/.config/chips/build.fish ; end

    echo "def interactive"
    # Don't use vi keybindings in unknown terminals,
    # since weird things can happen.
    set acceptable_terms xterm-256color screen-256color xterm-termite
    echo "acceptable terms: $acceptable_terms"
    echo "term: $TERM"
    if contains $TERM acceptable_terms
        echo "good to go!"
        fish_vi_key_bindings
        # Load pywal colors
        cat ~/.cache/wal/sequences
    else
       echo "why?!?!?"
    end
end
```

And what I'm getting is this:

```
so far so good
def interactive
acceptable terms: xterm-256color screen-256color xterm-termite
term: xterm-termite
why?!?!?
```

But what I expect to see is this:

```
so far so good
def interactive
acceptable terms: xterm-256color screen-256color xterm-termite
term: xterm-termite
good to go!
```

But when I run this in a shell, if works fine:

```
❯ echo "term: $TERM / acceptable: $acceptable_terms"                
term: xterm-termite / acceptable: xterm-256color screen-256color xterm-termite
❯ if contains $TERM $acceptable_terms                               
    echo "yay!"
  end
yay!
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: Notice your interactive test doesn't match what's in your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course fish can handle nested if statements!

> ```
>    if contains $TERM acceptable_terms
> ```

is missing the `$` on the second variable!

```
if contains $TERM $acceptable_terms
```